# Inverting frexp with ldexp

Tags: python, c++, precision

If I understand the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp) [correctly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ldexp), we should be able to use `ldexp` to recover a floating point number decomposed into a signed mantissa and an exponent by `frexp`. I have been unable to achieve this. Consider the following code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template <typename T>
void float_info() {
    std::cout << "max=" << std::numeric_limits<T>::max()          <<
        ", max_exp="    << std::numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent   <<
        ", max_10_exp=" << std::numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent10 <<
        ", min="        << std::numeric_limits<T>::min()          <<
        ", min_exp="    << std::numeric_limits<T>::min_exponent   <<
        ", min_10_exp=" << std::numeric_limits<T>::min_exponent10 <<
        ", dig="        << std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10       <<
        ", mant_dig="   << std::numeric_limits<T>::digits         <<
        ", epsilon="    << std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()      <<
        ", radix="      << std::numeric_limits<T>::radix          <<
        ", rounds="     << std::numeric_limits<T>::round_style    << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void compare(T a, T b) {
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " (" <<
        (a != b ? "un" : "") << "equal)" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void test_ldexp() {
    float_info<T>();

    T x = 1 + std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
    T y = ldexp(x, 0);
    int exponent;
    T mantissa = frexp(x, &exponent);
    T z = ldexp(mantissa, exponent);

    compare(x, y);
    compare(x, z);

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(25);
    test_ldexp<float>();
    test_ldexp<double>();
    test_ldexp<long double>();
}
```

When compiled with `g++` (version 4.8.4) on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, the output is:

```
max=3.402823466385288598117042e+38, max_exp=128, max_10_exp=38,
min=1.175494350822287507968737e-38, min_exp=-125, min_10_exp=-37, dig=6,
mant_dig=24, epsilon=1.1920928955078125e-07, radix=2, rounds=1
1.00000011920928955078125 1.00000011920928955078125 (equal)
1.00000011920928955078125 1.00000011920928955078125 (equal)

max=1.797693134862315708145274e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308,
min=2.225073858507201383090233e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15,
mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313080847263e-16, radix=2, rounds=1
1.000000000000000222044605 1.000000000000000222044605 (equal)
1.000000000000000222044605 1.000000000000000222044605 (equal)

max=1.189731495357231765021264e+4932, max_exp=16384, max_10_exp=4932,
min=3.362103143112093506262678e-4932, min_exp=-16381, min_10_exp=-4931, dig=18,
mant_dig=64, epsilon=1.084202172485504434007453e-19, radix=2, rounds=1
1.00000000000000000010842 1 (unequal)
1.00000000000000000010842 1 (unequal)
```

When using `long double`s we appear to be losing something by decomposing our `x` with `frexpr`. I can achieve the behavior I expect if I run the following script with `python3` (version 3.4.3).

```
import math
import sys

def compare(a, b):
    print('{a} {b} ({pre}equal)'.format(a=a, b=b,
        pre='un' if a != b else ''))

x = 1 + sys.float_info.epsilon
mantissa, exponent = math.frexp(x)

print(sys.float_info)
compare(x, math.ldexp(x, 0))
compare(x, math.ldexp(mantissa, exponent))
```

The output is:

```
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308,
min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15,
mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
1.0000000000000002 1.0000000000000002 (equal)
1.0000000000000002 1.0000000000000002 (equal)
```

Note that this is only using `double`s.

I tried to read the `cmath` header file to understand how `frexpr` and `ldexpr` are implemented, but I couldn't make sense of it. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your C++ program by including the `typeinfo` header and inserting the following lines right before the calls to `compare` in your `test_ldexp` function.

```
std::cout << "types:" << std::endl;
std::cout << "  x         : " << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "  mantissa  : " << typeid(frexp(x, &exponent)).name()
          << std::endl;
std::cout << "  ldexp(...): " << typeid(ldexp(x, 0)).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "  ldexp(...): " << typeid(ldexp(mantissa, exponent)).name()
          << std::endl;
```

The output is now:

```
max=3.402823466385288598117042e+38, max_exp=128, max_10_exp=38,
min=1.175494350822287507968737e-38, min_exp=-125, min_10_exp=-37, dig=6,
mant_dig=24, epsilon=1.1920928955078125e-07, radix=2, rounds=1
types:
  x         : f
  mantissa  : d
  ldexp(...): d
  ldexp(...): d
1.00000011920928955078125 1.00000011920928955078125 (equal)
1.00000011920928955078125 1.00000011920928955078125 (equal)

max=1.797693134862315708145274e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308,
min=2.225073858507201383090233e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15,
mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313080847263e-16, radix=2, rounds=1
types:
  x         : d
  mantissa  : d
  ldexp(...): d
  ldexp(...): d
1.000000000000000222044605 1.000000000000000222044605 (equal)
1.000000000000000222044605 1.000000000000000222044605 (equal)

max=1.189731495357231765021264e+4932, max_exp=16384, max_10_exp=4932,
min=3.362103143112093506262678e-4932, min_exp=-16381, min_10_exp=-4931, dig=18,
mant_dig=64, epsilon=1.084202172485504434007453e-19, radix=2, rounds=1
types:
  x         : e
  mantissa  : d
  ldexp(...): d
  ldexp(...): d
1.00000000000000000010842 1 (unequal)
1.00000000000000000010842 1 (unequal)
```

`frexpr` and `ldexpr` are returning `double`s no matter what type you put in! It appears that you are using the functions defined in `math.h` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/frexp) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ldexp)) instead those defined in `cmath`. Replace your calls to `frexpr` and `ldexpr` with calls to `std::frexpr` and `std::ldexpr` and your code will work as you expect.